# Combining data.table columns that include NAs

Tags: r, data.table

I have a set of five columns in a data table.

```
dt <- data.table(
  city = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,2), rep(3,2), rep(4,2)),
  neighborhoods.1 = c(NA, "a", "b", "c", NA, NA, "d", "e"),
  neighborhoods.2 = c(NA, "f", "g", rep(NA,5)),
  neighborhoods.3 = c(NA, "h", rep(NA, 6)),
  irrelevantdata = c(1:8)
)

   city neighborhoods.1 neighborhoods.2 neighborhoods.3 irrelevantdata
1:    1              NA              NA              NA              1
2:    1               a               f               h              2
3:    2               b               g              NA              3
4:    2               c              NA              NA              4
5:    3              NA              NA              NA              5
6:    3              NA              NA              NA              6
7:    4               d              NA              NA              7
8:    4               e              NA              NA              8
```

I want to combine the first four columns into a single column.

```
   neighborhood
1:    1
2:    1-a-f-h
3:    2-b-g
4:    2-c
5:    3
6:    3
7:    4-d
8:    4-e
```

As you can see, I'm removing `NA` records and separating with a `-`.

I've tried this, which has obvious problems in processing `j`:

```
business[
    , 
    neighborhood = paste0(
      city,
      if(!is.na(neighborhoods.1)) paste0("-", neighborhoods.1),
      if(!is.na(neighborhoods.2)) paste0("-", neighborhoods.2),
      if(!is.na(neighborhoods.3)) paste0("-", neighborhoods.3),       
      ""
    )
]
```

How can I get this done?

---

Updated to reflect that there are additional columns I don't want to combine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to `paste` the elements in rows together using `do.call`, and then remove the `NA` elements along with the extra `-` in the output vector.

```
dt[,.(neighborhood = gsub('-NA|NA-', '', 
   do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep='-')))), .SDcols= city:neighborhoods.3]
```

---

Or another option is group by sequence of rows, `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), remove the NA elements (`na.omit`), `paste` the elements together.  We can specify the columns to be used for this operation in `.SDcols`.

```
dt[, .(neighbourhood = paste(na.omit(unlist(.SD)),collapse='-')) , 
              by=1:nrow(dt), .SDcols= city:neighborhoods.3]
```

---

Or another option suggested by @Frank is to `melt` the subset of dataset (specified by the columns that are needed) to long format and then `paste`

```
 mycols <- setdiff(names(dt), 'irrelevantdata')
 na.omit(melt(dt[, ..mycols][, r := .I], 
      id.var="r"))[, paste(value, collapse="-"), by=r]
```

Comment: This works great for the example. My actual data.table has more columns that I don't want to combine here - where would I specify .SDcols?

Comment: @Chris, You can specify `.SDcols` within the `dt` i.e. `dt[, do.call(paste, c(.SD, list(sep='-'))), .SDcols=yourcols]`

Comment: The `NA` values return when I add the `.SDcols` to the example. Strange. I'm defining `.SDcols` by a vector of column names.

Comment: @Chris Can you update with an example.  I posted another less efficient solution.  Please check if that works.

Comment: First option works very fast with the edit! Second works as well but is pretty slow. Thanks akrun and @Frank